# How to get byte[] from image from local file for example /sdcard/tets.png?

Tags: android

How do I get a byte[] from an image stored in the local file system for example EG: `/sdcard/tets.png`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [IOUtils.toByteArray](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) from the Apache commons-io library. This is the easiest and the safest way I know. The commons-io library is tiny itself.

Something like this:

```
FileInputStream fileStream = null;
try {
    fileStream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/tets.png");
    final byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream);
    // Do something useful to the data
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
public static  byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        long length = file.length();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {

            offset += numRead;
        }

        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: This function leaks an InputStream if is.read(..) throws an IOException The is.close() statement doesn't get executed in this case.