# How to Insert Image in Sqlite Database?

Tags: android, android-activity

here I want to send my image in database.. but i Can't assign imgPro to values.put.. Please help me..

```
else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            imgPro.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


        }
```

Comment: get the byte array from the image. then convert it to string. then add that data to your database

Comment: could you plzz show me how to do this in above code.. please.. i am very new in android...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255526/how-to-get-byte-from-image-from-local-file-for-example-sdcard-tets-png

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below.

```
   public class ImageConverter {

    public static String imageToStringConverter(Bitmap image){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        String imageToString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return imageToString;
    }

    public static Bitmap stringToimageConverter(String imageString){
        byte[] stringTobyte = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stringTobyte, 0, stringTobyte.length);
        return bmp;
    }

}
```

You will call this two function to convert the image into string and then save in the database.Like below

```
String statusImage = ImageConverter.imageToStringConverter(selectedImage);
```

`selectedImage` is the bitmap you have selected from file. and if u want show the image then just again convert the string back to image.
Now why Base64??

> When you have some binary data that you want to ship across a network,
>   you generally don't do it by just streaming the bits and bytes over
>   the wire in a raw format.  Why?  because some media are made for
>   streaming text.  You never know -- some protocols may interpret your
>   binary data as control characters (like a modem), or your binary data
>   could be screwed up because the underlying protocol might think that
>   you've entered a special character combination (like how FTP
>   translates line endings).
>
> So to get around this, people encode the binary data into characters. 
>   Base64 is one of these types of encodings.  Why 64?  Because you can
>   generally rely on the same 64 characters being present in many
>   character sets, and you can be reasonably confident that your data's
>   going to end up on the other side of the wire uncorrupted.

Comment: see this link http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/23/when-you-should-use-base64-for-images/

Comment: i have updated my answer.check it.if it is useful then accept it so that other can get help from this answer.

Comment: Please give me simple example frnds.. please

Comment: I have updated buddy.But i don't understand why u are treating it as complex

Comment: dorry to disturb you but plz modifi my code what i had post.. I am seeing that my picure id displaying on ImageView. but m failed to send to database.. please help me if you could do this